# CSV imported file produces NAs after being processed with the same way with a created dataframe

Tags: r

My goal is to extract the time from a datetime column and display it inside a DT::datatable(). The case below works fine:

```
require(lubridate)
require(dplyr)

df = data.frame(timestring = c("2015-12-12 13:34:56", "2015-12-14 16:23:32"),
                localzone = c("America/Los_Angeles", "America/New_York"), stringsAsFactors = F)

df$moment = as.POSIXct(df$timestring, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")
df = df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(localtime = force_tz(moment, localzone))
df$t <- strftime(df$moment, format="%H:%M:%S")
df$t2 <- strftime(df$localtime, format="%H:%M:%S")
DT::datatable(df)
```

But when I try to do the same with a csv file that Import with:

```
    df2<-data.frame(read.csv("C:/Users/User/Documents/spotlight/Spotlight-SampleData/device1-report1583417393205.csv", header = TRUE))


ID EventType         EventDate EventValue EventValueExt1 EventValueExt2 EventValueExt3 EventValueExt4
1 12340     steps 2019-11-26T21:18Z       3017             NA             NA             NA             NA
2 12339     steps 2019-11-25T14:23Z       3016             NA             NA             NA             NA
```

and then process it:

```
df2$EventDate<-as.character(df2$EventDate)
df2$moment = as.POSIXct(df2$EventDate, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")
```

I get NAs in `df2$moment`

```
ID EventType         EventDate EventValue EventValueExt1 EventValueExt2 EventValueExt3 EventValueExt4 moment
1 12340     steps 2019-11-26T21:18Z       3017             NA             NA             NA             NA   <NA>
2 12339     steps 2019-11-25T14:23Z       3016             NA             NA             NA             NA   <NA>
```

Why does this happen? I even tried to convert `df2$EventDate` to character but it sill does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format you have in the csv is different than what you have in the example. Try using :

```
df2$moment = as.POSIXct(df2$EventDate, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M", tz="UTC")
```

Or use `lubridate`s `ymd_hm` where you don't need to worry about the format.

```
df2$moment <- lubridate::ymd_hm(df2$EventDate)
```